# .NET webservice consuming other webservice. Illegal Characters in XML from first webservice

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net, web-services

I'm writing a webservice that is calling another webservice.

One of the functions called is the "viewticket",  discovered by .NET as per below.

```
        '''<remarks/>
    <System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace:="http://blablabla.com", ResponseNamespace:="http://blablabla.com")> _
    Public Function viewTicket(ByVal sentinelUser As SentinelUser, ByVal [string] As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("result")> SentinelResponse
        Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("viewTicket", New Object() {sentinelUser, [string]})
        Return CType(results(0), SentinelResponse)
    End Function
```

The returned SentinelResponse is an XML file that has a couple of fields

```
- <xsd:complexType name="Fields">
 - <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="BTN" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="CPUID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="DNIS" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="DNSHostname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="Description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="Kweethetniet" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" /> 
  .....
```

The **description** field  in the database behind it somehow seems sometimes populated with illegal characters (ascii 1-20).
As soon as the field is being called to be fetched, i get an error

```
    ' '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable:=True)> _
    Public Property descriptionText() As String
        Get
            Return Me.descriptionTextField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.descriptionTextField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Is there a way to 'intercept' the returned XML stream from the called webservice and run it first through a regex.replace to filter these illegal characters out?

I don't have access to the backend system  unfortunately.

Comment: I think you can stream XML to processors where you could handle events.

Comment: The RegEx `[\cA-\cZ]` should pick up all "illegal" characters.